# Deployment of destructive changes to production and tests execution

Tags: unit-test, deployment, migration-tool, destructivechanges.xml

We need to remove trigger and apex test class for it from production org.
We've already put together destructiveChanges.xml and are going to deploy it to prod org via ant migration tool.

The question here is: would such deployment cause tests execution in prod org?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all tests will be forced to run, since the code base is being altered. In addition, all classes will be recompiled to ensure that nothing is broken as a result of the deployment.